# Passing form parameters between views in Pyramid

Tags: python, forms, pyramid

I am creating a form that requires user confirmation before submitting the data. I would like a seperate confirmation page because I need to display quite a bit information about how the form data will be processed. I was wondering if there was a pythonic way to pass data between forms in Pyramid.

Submitting the form takes the user to the confirmation page. Thus, the view for the confirmation has the form data stored in `request.POST`. I was wondering if there was a clean way to pass along all of this data to the final view once the user hits 'submit' on the confirmation page. I would also like to add a boolean variable, confirmed, to the dictionary of parameters.

Comment: Also, is there a general way to do this that doesn't requiring knowing the names of the form parameters?

Comment: I can't actually think of a way to do this that *does* require knowing the names of the parameters....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Pyramid-specific answer, but two common approaches to this problem are:

1. Store the data in a session.
2. Store the data as a hidden form on the confirmation page, and resubmit with "confirmed"

I like 2 much better because it's a stateless method.  You can also use the exact same form processing logic, and just check for the presence of your "confirmed" POST variable to decide which action to take and view to show (i.e, either the "please confirm" view, or processing and the "processed" view.)

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to pass the form data to the confirmed template so that I can generate the hidden form. I posted some code above. Thanks!