# Passing data between form views in Pyramid

Tags: frameworks, pyramid

I'm making a project in pyramid framework, so i have a view which have a form in it with 2 input type texts and a submit button.

The form is a post method, so im getting them with a POST request.

I want to send them to a new view and display them on the screen.
meaning:

- on 0.0.0.0:6543 is the form on first view.
- I want to display the values the user insert in the input on 0.0.0.0:6543/here

I tried with HTTPfound but i guess im missing an understanding on how to really pass the variables.

Please help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing form parameters between views in Pyramid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409521/passing-form-parameters-between-views-in-pyramid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to pass the data from one view to another is via the URL. This does not require server-side support, unlike sessions. Also, it's RESTful ;)

```
return HTTPFound('/here?greeting=Hello&subject=World')
```

In your second view you then simply get the variables from `request.GET`:

```
greeting = request.GET.get('greeting', '')
subject = request.GET.get('subject', '')
# pass the data to the template
return {
    "greeting": greeting,
    "subject": subject
}
```

Regarding your comment: You can't use HTTPFound with POST. You can, however, directly submit your form to `/here` using `<form method="post" action="/here" ...>`. In this case you'll be able to access the data using `request.POST.get('greeting')`.

Comment: Thank you Sergey but I want it to come from a POST method and not GET. Is this possible?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I wouldn't call it "passing data between views", although, technically, that's what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish is to use [sessions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/sessions.html).

- You need a session backend which stores your data on a server (see [pyramid_redis_session](https://github.com/ericrasmussen/pyramid_redis_sessions)). There are also cookie-based session solutions where all data is stored on the client side.
- The first view writes all passed over data to a session:

  ```
  request.session["mydata"] = value
  ```
- The second view reads data from the session

  ```
   print(request.session["mydata"])
  ```

Comment: Thank you dude. That's helpful :) but I was wandering also if i can make it restful so that the second view gets it with POST